# if statement with empty UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is loaded form a text file.  Sometimes the text file has something in it and sometimes it is empty.  So sometimes the UILabel is blank and sometimes it has text in it.

I want to write an if statement that says if the UILabel is blank do one thing else if it has text in it do another thing.

I have tried

```
if (self.label.text = NULL)
```

and

```
if (self.label.text = @"")
```

but it isn't working correctly.

With the `if (self.label.text = @"")`, I get the if statement to happen but the else statement doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
NSString *stuff3 = @"/Stuff";
NSString *titleName = [familyDictionary objectForKey:@"identity"];

NSArray *paths3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory3 = [paths3 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *stuffPath3 = [documentsDirectory3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:stuff3];
NSString *fullPath3 = [stuffPath3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:titleName];

self.title = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath3  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSLog(@"full path 3 >>>%@",fullPath3);

NSString *stuff4 = @"/Stuff/Objects";
NSString *textName3 = [familyDictionary objectForKey:@"identity"];
NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *stuffPath = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:stuff4];
NSString *fullPath2 = [stuffPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:textName3];
self.wordlabel.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath2  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

//Now load the image at fullPath and install it into our image view's image property.
 NSLog(@"full path 3 >>>%@",fullPath2);

if(self.wordlabel.text = @"") 
{
    [textView setTitle:[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath3  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
    textView.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
}
else
{
    [textView setTitle:[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath2  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
    textView.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is comparing pointers, which doesn't work with strings.  Use this

```
if ([self.wordlabel.text isEqualToString:@"thestring"])
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong, wrong.

Wrong 1: `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the equality operator. You're using the assignment operator inside an if statement, you should at least be getting a compiler warning about that.

Wrong 2: Even if you had that bit right, it's the wrong way to compare strings. Use `isEqualToString:` or check length as in the other answers.

Wrong 3: The logic should probably be based on the strings before you assign them to the label, not by reading back what is in the label. It's a cleaner MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you should ideally use:

```
if ([self.label.text length] > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `self.label.text = @""` **you are changing your label's text**. `=` is the assignment operator. **`==` is the comparison operator.**

**However**, to compare strings, you must use the comparison method `[self.label.text isEqualToString:@""]`, otherwise you are just comparing pointers.