# Creating a translator/dictionary in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So Im importing a text file that contains a list of character sets. These sets have a meaning they refer to a status of an object. For example TOMTOM100 means Delivery announced. Ones i import he text file the status is presented in 0-5 labels(depends on how many status updates are available).

At first i wanted to do this with a if statement but quickly realized that it would be to much.

```
    if ((trackTraceStatusone.text = @"TOMTOM100")) 
                {
                    trackTraceStatusone.text = @"Delivery announced.";
                }
```

Is there a way to create some kind of translator that automatically translates the status in a readable format?

TOMTOM100 > Delivery announced

TOMTOM101 > Delivery Scanned

and so on.

Comment: Side note: you need to use `isEqualToString:` rather than `==` or even worse, `=`! See [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14549659/23649).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`NSLocalizedStringFromTable()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedStringFromTable) or the corresponding NSBundle method [`-localizedStringForKey:value:table:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/localizedStringForKey%3avalue%3atable%3a). This will let you load the string from a `.strings` file in your bundle, which will look something like this:

```
"TOMTOM100" = "Delivery Announced";
"TOMTOM101" = "Delivery Scanned";
```

This will also make it easy to provide different strings for different languages. For more information, see the [String Resources section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6) of the Resource Programming Guide.